I am unable to get Promise.allSettled() to trigger when the provided Promises are fulfilled
I am trying to create a list of Promises for collecting data from an API, and then once all of the Promises are fulfilled (either resolved or rejected, it doesn't matter), run another call to the API.  However, somewhere along the line, something is not correctly resolving and I am not sure where.  Promise.all() with the same array will trigger, but not Promise.allSettled().
const attachments = [1,2,3,4];
let attachmentUploadsList = [];

attachments.forEach((attachment, index) => {
  attachmentUploadsList.push(
    uploadAttachment().then((response) => {
      if (response) {
        console.log("success"); // WORKS
        return Promise.resolve(true);
      } else {
        console.log("error"); // WORKS
        return Promise.reject(false);
      }
    })
  );
});

Promise.all(attachmentUploadsList).then(() => {
  console.log("Run this if all succeed"); // WORKS
});

Promise.allSettled(attachmentUploadsList).then(() => {
  console.log("Run this if all complete even with a reject"); // DOESN'T WORK
});

const uploadAttachment = async () => {
  const apiUrl = "https://url/api/";
  let payload = {};
  return await fetch(apiUrl, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  })
    .then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.text();
      }
    })
    .then((result) => {
      return result;
    });
};

The above code is the closest I have come to getting it to work, but I am not sure where to go from there.

"will trigger": what does that mean? An exception occurs? You get a rejected promise? You get a resolved promise?

Also, what does "DOESN'T WORK" mean? It doesn't get executed? In that case, the presence of the completeExportJob call is not the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem: it could just be a console.log... Can you provide the minimum code needed to reproduce the issue, and be clear about what exactly is different from expectation?

Promise.all() will run the code in the .then() block (when all the fetch promises succeed), but Promise.allSettled() will not.  Using a console.log() in the Promise.allSettled().then() block will never show anything in the console, but with Promise.all().then() it will.

I have updated the code to make it clearer as the completeExportJob is not relevant.  I would expect to get:
"Run this if all succeed"
"Run this if all complete even with a reject"
in the console, but all I ever will get is the first line, never the second line.

Are the calls to updateFileQueueState necessary to reproduce the issue? Are the parameters of the function uploadAttachment necessary to reproduce the issue? Can you please make sure we can reproduce the issue by running the code ourselves, and minimise it?

I cannot reproduce the behaviour you describe. This code puts ES6 promise objects in attachmentUploadsList, and these guarantee to follow the "contract" that promises cannot change their resolution. When Promise.all() fulfills, then it means all those promises are in a fulfilled state. And thus Promise.allSetlled() will necessarily also fulfill. Please provide more debugging details.

@user28696693 What are you on about? allSettled returns a promise, which will always resolve to an array of objects with fullfilled and status (and value in case of success) in it (unless a promise never resolves and hangs forever, which can happen)? Even then, you aren't even using its return value anyway?

Try not to mix .then with async/await. It's much better to stick to one.

I am wondering whether the issue is WebView2 - the minimised code above works for me sperately in Chrome and Edge, but when I try to run it in a WebView2 window (it is through an Outlook add-in) it just seems to stop when it gets to Promise.allSettled(), even if it just has an empty array as a parameter.  Is it possible that Promise.allSettled() isn't supported by WebView2?  According to MDN it is supported in all browsers and there is no error being thrown in the console.

If you have a question that concerns WebView2, then please tag it with that. Note that Promise.allSettled was introduced with ES2020, while Promise.all existed already since ES2015.

I am not sure if it is WebView2 or a package/node issue, but either way I don't think the issue is with my code, it's some sort of compatibility issue, so I will start a new question as it is now very different to what I thought my original issue was.  Thank you for getting me this far @trincot.
